# Bug with Grails Criteria, PagedResultList and offset?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Given the following code in Grails 3.1:

```
def c = Book.createCriteria()
def result = c.list(params) {
    // some criteria
}

println "count = ${result.totalCount}\n records = ${result}"
```

If "params" includes "offset:0" and the number of returned records is small (say less than 10) then "totalCount" is correct, but "result" is empty - there are no records in it.

But if "offset" is not in "params", then the results are as expected - "result" contains the list of returned records.

Is this a bug with the "offset" parameter? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Which Grails version?

Comment: Version 3.1.9. Not the latest, but not far behind.

Comment: Upload an example project and create a github issue